# do_blocks not working with a custom block

Tags: php, block-editor

i am trying to render one of my custom blocks inside a PHP file:

```
<?php
    $block_content = do_blocks( '
        <!-- wp:create-block/gb-button-block  /-->'
    );

    echo $block_content; 
    ?>
```

The result, it doesnt display the button:

[image]

Now if i try it with an official wordpress block:

```
<?php
    $block_content = '<!-- wp:latest-posts {"postsToShow":3,"displayPostContent":true,"excerptLength":30,"displayPostDate":true,"postLayout":"grid","displayFeaturedImage":true,"featuredImageSizeSlug":"large","align":"wide","className":"tw-mt-8 tw-img-ratio-3-2 tw-stretched-link is-style-default"} /-->';
    
    echo do_blocks($block_content);
    ?>
```

It works perfectly:

[image]

Idk if im doing something wrong, the button block works perfectly outside of this PHP example.

Thank you!

Comment: How does your block work? Is it a dynamic block rendered on the server? Or is the block data saved as HTML?  In the editor, add your block, then copy the block and paste it into a text editor. Whatever is pasted is what you need to pass to `do_blocks()`.

Comment: It is a Static block, i did as you said and it worked perfectly!.